# font-lock-add-keywords regexp for C++ operators

Tags: regex, emacs, emacs-faces

I have a regexp that finds and highlights operators in C++ but I can't for the life of me work out how to match `operator[]` using regexp. The usual trick of escaping the characters doesn't seem to work, it merely ends matching.

```
    (font-lock-add-keywords
     nil '(
       ;; operators
       ("[~^&\|!<>:=,.\\+*/%-]" . font-lock-keyword-face) ))
```

My second (incomplete) attempt using `regexp-builder` and moving escaped symbols to the end of the match got me the opening brace:

```
    ("[~^=<>&/.,\[\|\*\+\-]" . font-lock-keyword-face)
```

but adding `\]` or moving `\[` kills any matching. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match a literal `]`, put it right after the opening `[`:

```
"[]~^=<>&/.,\[\|\*\+\-]"
```

Since an empty character choice wouldn't make any sense in a regexp, this combination is given the alternative interpretation of matching an actual `]`.

Comment: Neat catch on the initial `]` -- I never knew that.

Answer (score 3):

I use `regexp-opt` for this, because it's much more readable.  Relevant config:

```
(setq operators-font-lock-spec
      (cons (regexp-opt '("+" "-" "*" "/" "%" "!"
                          "&" "^" "~" "|"
                          "=" "<" ">"
                          "." "," ";" ":" "?"))
            (list
             0 ;; use whole match
             'font-lock-builtin-face
             'keep ;; OVERRIDE
             )))

(setq brackets-font-lock-spec
      (cons (regexp-opt '("(" ")" "[" "]" "{" "}"))
            (list
             0 ;; use whole match
             'font-lock-bracket-face
             'keep ;; OVERRIDE
             )))

(font-lock-add-keywords
 'c++-mode
 (list
  operators-font-lock-spec
  brackets-font-lock-spec
  (cons c-types-regexp 'font-lock-type-face)))
```

`brackets-font-lock-spec` is separate because I use a different face for them.

Comment: You may also want to look at `rx`.

Answer (score 2):

You need **two** consecutive backslashes to escape a character for a regular expression in a literal string, i.e.

```
"[]~^&|!<>:=,.+\\[*/%-]"
```

A single backslash is interpreted by the Emacs Lisp reader when parsing the string literal, and denotes escape sequences, e.g. `\n` for a newline character.  If the backslash doesn't start a known escape sequence as in this case (`\[` is no special character), the backslash is simply dropped.  In this case, a single `[` ends up in the resulting string, which creates an invalid regular expression and thus prevents it from matching.

Comment: Suggest adding the first `]` as in @legoscia's answer, as the current regex won't match the close bracket otherwise.  Also, unless I'm mistaken, you can unescape the `+`, as it will be treated as a literal inside square brackets.

Comment: @Dan Thanks, I updated my answer accordingly.  I didn't really look at the contents of the expression, I just noticed and fix the flawed escaping.  I should have read the question more carefully.

Comment: Part of my problem is that `re-builder` only displays the first 200 matches. Removing the `\\ ==============` style comments got me further and showed that you were correct. Thanks all!